# UIDocumentPickerViewController buttons look disabled but work -- why?

Tags: ios, uidocumentpickervc, files-app

I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController to export images to the Files app in iOS 11. The picker comes up, and I am able to pick a destination for the files. I get the callback that the files were moved and I can see them in Files, so that appears to be working fine. However, the UI is wrong -- the Add and Cancel buttons look disabled, but they actually work fine. The buttons don't look this way if I just use Save to Files in the Share Sheet.

This is my code:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *docPicker = 
[[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithURLs:self.assetURLs inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService];

docPicker.delegate = self;
[vc presentViewController:docPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Things I have tried:
1) I have tried both Move and Export types 
2) I have enabled the iCloud capability (all three items: key-value, Document, and CloudKit) - no difference in the experience [in fact, the code worked even without these set, though the docs say otherwise])

Here is an screenshot of what the UI looks like. As you can see, the UI says it will add the item to the chosen directory (and it, in fact, does if I tap on Add):
[image]

Anyone know how to get the buttons to appear blue and look enabled? I have not found any sample code online that I could try -- if someone has a pointer, I can try that to see if it's something about my configuration or code.

Comment: Is your app doing anything to alter any related appearances in other parts of your app?

Comment: That's a great question. My app is dark, so I have a few appearance changes. I disabled them and the blue came back. Turns out that UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor somehow affects these buttons, even though I don't think they should. Not sure how I am going to work around it, but at least I have an explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor yourColor]; // for button title color and [UINavigationBar appearance].backgroundColor = [UIColor yourColor]; // for background color. Worked for me like a charm. I have this issue only iOS 14 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, your app is setting the `tintColor` using `UINavigationBar.appearance`. This will affect all navigation bars, including those of system navigation controller such as `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

I've dealt with this in one of my own apps. One solution is to subclass `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and to use your subclass anywhere you need the picker view. In your subclass, override `viewDidLoad` and set `UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor` back to `nil`. And also override `viewWillDisappear` to reset `UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor` back to the desired color.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a big fan of temporarily changing the global appearance like suggested in the approved answer. You can just reset the appearance for UIDocumentPickerViewController and the bar buttons will return to their original blue.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil
}
```